# Can/should answers be moved after substantial edits of the question?

Tags: support

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39336/given-small-computational-resources-how-navigation-was-implemented-not-samples) originally asked for samples of old guidance/spacecraft software, which is an interesting question, which I [answered](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39337/20987) with one example. However, at some point during some interaction between the question asker and the author of one of the answer, the question asker realised that they actually wanted to know something else ([XY problem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

I suggested to edit the question to better reflect the true question, since there were now two answers that answer the actual question better:

> @Arjang To be honest, the current accepted answer does not answer the question "Samples of old guidance software". I suggest that you either edit the question so it better reflects what you really wanted to know (how spacecraft guidance computers work, given small computational resources) or ask that in a another question and edit this question to limit answers to examples of old guidance software source code. In this way future visitors will find what they expect from the question title. – Ludo 2 days ago

The OP did so and asked a [second question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39378/samples-of-old-guidance-software-using-computational-resources-on-earth-implemen), which is actually their original question.

Now, question 1 has two relevant answer and one irrelevant answer (mine), which has actually quite some votes. Question 2 has zero answers at this moment, but my answer should be there.

Should I:

1. Duplicate my answer in the second question and leave it in the original one;
2. Duplicate my answer in the second question and delete my answer in the original one; or
3. Move my answer from the first question to the second question (if this is possible); or
4. Forget about it?

Was there a better way to handle this from my side instead of commenting to the first question (i.e. the above quoted comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually we ask users not to so drastically change the scope of the question after there are answers with upvotes. It is too late to reverse what has happened, however. Now, unfortunately we are stuck with a situation where there is no mechanism to move your answer to the other question and maintain the votes on it.

My suggestion is to add a note to the top of the answer to explain that it addressed the original form of the question which has been spun off into a separate question (provide a link). Then you can copy and paste your answer over to the other question. I suppose someone might accuse you of trying to get more rep, but if it comes up we can point them to this meta discussion where I advised you to take this course of action.

Comment: At one point I flagged the edit to the question, then the OP explained they thought they were acting on a request for an answer's author. Perhaps I should have left the flag in place. It seems everyone was acting in good faith.

Comment: @uhoh Yeah, I think it was ok, but I would have avoided it knowing all of the details. If the answers had hardly any upvotes it would be different.